# Function with array returning 0 Visual Basic

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I'm quite new at using arrays and functions in Visual Basic and I cannot seem to figure this out. My problem is that whenever I call the function `Fibo` it returns 0 no matter the value of `n` I give it. I'm sure the error is pretty basic.

Any pointer would be really appreciated!

```
Public Function fibo(n As Integer) As Integer

    Dim arrayFib(n + 1) As Integer 'declare array to hold fibonacci

    arrayFib(0) = 0 'idem
    arrayFib(1) = 1 'declare start value

    Dim i As Integer = 2 'start position

    While i <= n
        arrayFib(i) = arrayFib(i - 1) + arrayFib(i - 2)
        i = 1 + i

    Return arrayFib(i)
```

Comment: You missed `End While`. Just copy/paste mistake, or there is no `End While` in your code?

Comment: `i` becomes `n + 1` and that value in the array is `0` (default value of INT). And also, should have `End While` (should even through an index out of bound exception).

Comment: @Cybȫʁgϟ37 It's an array of `Integer`s, so there is no problem about the returning of a value (the type).

Answer (score 3):

```
Dim arrayFib(n + 1) As Integer 'declare array to hold fibonacci
```

We can sort of guess where that +1 came from.  You added it because your original code crashed with an IndexOutOfRangeException.  Caused by you returning arrayFib(i), i was incremented to be *larger* than n, its value is n+1 after the loop.  And thus returns the value of an element that was never assigned.  You didn't fix it correctly :)

Fix the array declaration back the way it was and return arrayFib(n) instead.

Comment: If n is the number of Fibonacci digits to return, then the array declaration should be `Dim arrayFib(n - 1) As Integer` since in VB, the value specified when declaring an array is the upper bound, not the array size.